# Find Next in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

We have a bunch of documents we would like to convert to Google Docs. In MSWord we have a macro where our users hit a key command and it will automatically find a string of characters (%%%) and then select them. So we can quickly go in and replace all occurrences of them with the correct data.

I am unable to find anything in Google Docs or scripts that can do that.

TL;DR
I need to write a script that will find and select text so we can quickly write over it. Any help or thoughts?

Comment: What do you know about writing scripts for Google Documents?

Answer (score 0):

**This function works in conjunction with a sidebar to find and select text.**

```
function findTextAndSelect(s){
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var rgel=body.findText(s);
  if(rgel){
    var rgbldr=doc.newRange();
    rgbldr.addElement(rgel.getElement(),rgel.getStartOffset(),rgel.getEndOffsetInclusive());
    var rg=rgbldr.build();
    if(rg.getRangeElements().length>0){
      doc.setSelection(rgbldr.build());
      return 'found';
    }
    else{
      return 'Not Found';
    }
  }else{
    return 'Not Found';
  }
}
```

**This is the sidebar code. **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#txt1').val('');
      });
    function findAndSelect(){
      $('#status').html('');
      var txt=$('#txt1').val();
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
          $('#status').html('<strong>Status:</strong>' + hl);
        })
        .findTextAndSelect(txt);
    }
    console.log("My code");
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <br />Text:<br /><textarea id="txt1" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea>
  <br /><input type="button" id="btn3" value="Find Text and Select" onClick="findAndSelect();" />
  <div id="status"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

You need to add the code to load the sidebar and possibly put it into the menu.